# Designing JPA entities for legacy database table with lot of columns

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, entity, jpa-2.0

We are working on rewriting a legacy application using Java EE, Spring, JPA and JSF.  The work is in early stages of designing. We looked at the existing database. There are couple of tables with lot of columns. One of them have around 800 columns. Plan is to normalize the tables and data.

I was just wondering if there are upper boundaries for creating JPA 2.0 entities for tables with large number of columns. I understand that small tables are better.

Any suggestions on how I should approach the design?

Answer (score 1):

If it comes to design - there's not much you can do about it. One simple approach, to keep code quite clean, is to extract some common-domain columns and create `@Embeddable` classes from them.

Another option is to create materialized views with columns that are to be retrieved togeter, and create separate read-only entities for them - this would work only if you don't plan to write anything to them.

AFAIK `JPA` and its biggest providers are not restricted to any number of columns in a table, but the cost of performing operations such as `findAll()` on such entity would be probably really harmful.

Comment: What about find by example? Can we achieve better performance by using caching or lazy loading?

Comment: It is probably best to use both of them. Lazy loading can be the substitute for dividing table into many views and its able to write to the table.

Comment: Thanks Maciej. Mostly we pull one record at a time. So, I would like to get your thoughts on findByExample performance. I was told that at a time we may display max of 100 fields of a database row from this table on UI (front end) page.